# How to combine these lists in one single list?

Tags: python

I have this list (asList) It is read from a file and now i need do separate it  by the colons and to create new list of lists

```
asList =  ['green:g----:g::g\n', '\n', 'green:gr---:r::gr\n', '\n', 'green:gree-:e::gre\n', '\n', 'green:green:n::gren\n', '\n']
```

after this for loop

```
for i in asList:
    print i.split(":")
```

the result is this:

```
['green', 'g----', 'g', '', 'g\n']
['green', 'gr---', 'r', '', 'gr\n']
['green', 'gree-', 'e', '', 'gre\n']
['green', 'green', 'n', '', 'gren\n']
```

and now i need to combine these 4 lists into one single list of lists with 4 elements (each list to be one element) but i don't have any idea of how to do it. Please can someone help me here? Thank you

Comment: use list comprehension for that.. to work easiy

Comment: `combinedList = list(i.split(":") for i in asList)` (untested)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
listOfLists = [i.split(":") for i in asList]
```

Or change the for loop you have to append them to the parent list:

```
listOfLists = []
for i in asList:
    listOfLists.append(i.split(":"))
```

These both do the same thing. List comprehensions are more concise (and readable, I think), the for loop is a bit more flexible if you want to do more to the sublists before adding them to the `listOfLists`.

Comment: and if you want to get rid of whitespace use `[row.strip().split(':') for row in asList if row.strip()]`

Comment: Thanks this was of great help, thow i can't understand why to use stri() where are these whitespaces?

Comment: The '\n' characters at the end of each line are newlines, which are considered whitespace. You can use .strip() on the lines (before splitting them) to get rid of the newlines if you don't want them.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have read in a file and already split on \n. Why not

data = open('foo','r').read().replace('\n',':').split(':')

Comment: I think that this can't work because readlines() return a list and replace() is method fot str only (atleast this is the mistake that i get)